# How can I calculate this number without so many variables?

Tags: python

I have all these variables, and it just seems too cluttered to me.

```
text1 = "ABCD" + " : " + "EFGH"
text2 = str(3.06) + "% : " + "XYZ"

# The text is not actually equal to "ABCD", "EFGH", and "XYZ"

num1 = int(len(str(text1)))
num2 = int(len(str(text2)))
num3 = int(num1 - num2)
num4 = int(num3/2)
num5 = num4*" "
```

Is there any way I could simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace the operations in the place of each variable. It works similar as mathematics:

```
num = " " * int((len(text1) - len(text2))/2)
```

**Note** that is not necessary to explicitly *cast* to `str` the variables `text1` and `text2` since they are already of type `str`. You can see this by printing

```
print(type(text1))
```

If you are using Python 2.7, then it's not necessary to cast the division to `int`. But if it's Python 3.x then it will be unnecessary.

Comment: @lejlot is not clear if OP is using Python 2.7 or 3.x. In the last one, an `int/int` will result in a `float`.

Comment: If you want to do integer division in Python 3, it is better to use the `//` floor division operator than use the float division operator `/` and cast the result to an integer. Doing so is just wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

```
" " * ((len(text1) - len(text2))/2)
```

Comment: Be aware that this works in Python 2, but in Python 3 the division returns `float` and you can't multiply a string by a `float`. So there's one `int` in the questioner's original code that isn't redundant :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are performing many redundant convesions (of strings to strings and ints to ints)

```
text1 = "ABCD" + " : " + "EFGH"
text2 = str(3.06) + "% : " + "XYZ"

# The text is not actually equal to "ABCD", "EFGH", and "XYZ"

num1 = len(text1)
num2 = len(text2)
num3 = num1 - num2
num4 = num3/2
num5 = num4*" "
```

you can also compress last 5 operations in just one

```
num5 = " " * (( len(text1)-len(text2) ) / 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2: `" " * ((len(text1) - len(text2))/2)`

In Python 3: `" " * ((len(text1) - len(text2))//2)` (because you want integer division)